# Auto start elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Within Elastic Beanstalk, is it possible to setup an auto scaling group, between 0 and 1 instances, and have the environment sit at 0 instances, until the first HTTP request hits the ELB, and then have a new instance created/started for a specified period of time?

I don't care about the time taken to spin up the instance, as this is only for test environments.

EB allows me to set 0 instances in the scaling section, (which *red's* the environment), but I cant get the auto scaling group to activate the instance when required.

Comment: No, EB will have a minimum of 1 instance.

Comment: Can you elaborate please, I currently have an EB with 0 instances. Are you saying there is no way for me to autoscale to 1? If that is the case, you can put that as an answer, and I'll (sadly) accept it.

Comment: If you can have an EB environment with 0 instances, without it being in some sort of error state, then that's something I wasn't aware you could do.

Comment: It is in an error state(I mention 'red the env.' in my question), I want to bring it to green, on the first HTTP request.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware you could do that. Is this a load-balanced environment, or a single-instance environment?

Comment: Currently its load-balanced.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify your autoscaling group to trigger a scale-up operation based on the `RequestCount` metric on your Elastic Load Balancer is greater than 0.